# What's wrong with Android CalendarView

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to show a `Dialog` with a `CalendarView`. This is how i display the `Dialog`:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_calendart, null);
            builder.setView(v);
            builder.create().show();
```

and this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CalendarView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This works fine when the `Dialog` doesn't contain a `CalendarView`, when it does the `Dialog` takes several seconds to display and I noticed loads of these lines in my `LogCat`:

```
07-03 12:39:37.304    1534-1534/de.something.debug I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 270 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-03 12:39:37.348    1534-1534/de.something.debug D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1621K, 10% free 18334K/20160K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
```

When it finally shows the `Dialog` looks like this:

[image]

I also tried to set a date to the `CalendarView` like

```
calendarView.setDate(23423423);
```

but it still didnt show anya dates.

What's going wrong there?

Comment: even you not able see this dialog also ah? "july 2014"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in your layout and try

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <CalendarView 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:minHeight="200dp" 
                  android:minWidth="200dp"
                  android:maxDate="01/01/2013"
                 android:minDate="09/01/2012"/>
                  </LinearLayout>
```